# Case statement check for negative value

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have the below case statement, which can generate negative values as well based not the calculations

I am looking for a way to add another case statement that if after all the calculations the value <0 then 0 else the value.

```
CASE WHEN (ALS.SID = 6 OR ALS.SID = 7) AND ASIP.SiteID = @iSID 
    THEN ISNULL(ALS.Add / NULLIF(count,0),0.0)
                       ELSE CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (4, 6) AND @forecast = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE IAOD.pack END - 
                            CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) AND @forecast = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE IAOD.packP END + 
                            CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) AND @forecast = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE IAOD.packR END + 
     ISNULL(CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) THEN CAST(NULL AS FLOAT) 
                 ELSE IAOD.packS
            END,
            CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) THEN 0.0 
                 ELSE IAOD.PPStock 
            END) + 
                            CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (4, 6) AND @forecast = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE IAOD.unitsO END -
                            CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) AND @forecast = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE IAOD.unitsP END + 
                            CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) AND @forecast = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE IAOD.unitsR END + 
     ISNULL(CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) 
                 THEN CAST(NULL AS FLOAT) 
                 ELSE IAOD.unitsS 
            END,
            CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) 
                 THEN 0.0 
                 ELSE IAOD.unitsH 
            END) 
END
```

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*. `cross apply` it as a calculation then use another case to 0 any negative values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap it up with another case when like below:

```
case when (CASE WHEN (ALS.SID = 6 OR ALS.SID = 7) AND ASIP.SiteID = @iSID 
    THEN ISNULL(ALS.Add / NULLIF(count,0),0.0)
                       ELSE CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (4, 6) AND @forecast = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE IAOD.pack END - 
                            CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) AND @forecast = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE IAOD.packP END + 
                            CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) AND @forecast = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE IAOD.packR END + 
     ISNULL(CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) THEN CAST(NULL AS FLOAT) 
                 ELSE IAOD.packS
            END,
            CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) THEN 0.0 
                 ELSE IAOD.PPStock 
            END) + 
                            CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (4, 6) AND @forecast = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE IAOD.unitsO END -
                            CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) AND @forecast = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE IAOD.unitsP END + 
                            CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) AND @forecast = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE IAOD.unitsR END + 
     ISNULL(CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) 
                 THEN CAST(NULL AS FLOAT) 
                 ELSE IAOD.unitsS 
            END,
            CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) 
                 THEN 0.0 
                 ELSE IAOD.unitsH 
            END) 
END) <0 then 0 else (CASE WHEN (ALS.SID = 6 OR ALS.SID = 7) AND ASIP.SiteID = @iSID 
    THEN ISNULL(ALS.Add / NULLIF(count,0),0.0)
                       ELSE CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (4, 6) AND @forecast = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE IAOD.pack END - 
                            CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) AND @forecast = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE IAOD.packP END + 
                            CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) AND @forecast = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE IAOD.packR END + 
     ISNULL(CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) THEN CAST(NULL AS FLOAT) 
                 ELSE IAOD.packS
            END,
            CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) THEN 0.0 
                 ELSE IAOD.PPStock 
            END) + 
                            CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (4, 6) AND @forecast = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE IAOD.unitsO END -
                            CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) AND @forecast = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE IAOD.unitsP END + 
                            CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) AND @forecast = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE IAOD.unitsR END + 
     ISNULL(CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) 
                 THEN CAST(NULL AS FLOAT) 
                 ELSE IAOD.unitsS 
            END,
            CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) 
                 THEN 0.0 
                 ELSE IAOD.unitsH 
            END) 
END) end
```

Or You can write the whole query then select from that query with the case expression as below :

```
select case when a<0 then 0 else a from (
select (CASE WHEN (ALS.SID = 6 OR ALS.SID = 7) AND ASIP.SiteID = @iSID 
    THEN ISNULL(ALS.Add / NULLIF(count,0),0.0)
                       ELSE CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (4, 6) AND @forecast = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE IAOD.pack END - 
                            CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) AND @forecast = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE IAOD.packP END + 
                            CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) AND @forecast = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE IAOD.packR END + 
     ISNULL(CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) THEN CAST(NULL AS FLOAT) 
                 ELSE IAOD.packS
            END,
            CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) THEN 0.0 
                 ELSE IAOD.PPStock 
            END) + 
                            CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (4, 6) AND @forecast = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE IAOD.unitsO END -
                            CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) AND @forecast = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE IAOD.unitsP END + 
                            CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) AND @forecast = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE IAOD.unitsR END + 
     ISNULL(CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) 
                 THEN CAST(NULL AS FLOAT) 
                 ELSE IAOD.unitsS 
            END,
            CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) 
                 THEN 0.0 
                 ELSE IAOD.unitsH 
            END) 
END) a from table)t
```

Answer (score 0):

I find `CROSS APPLY` the neatest way to avoid duplicating the calculation.

```
SELECT *
  , CASE WHEN X.MyCalculation < 0 THEN 0 ELSE X.MyCalculation END
FROM MyTable
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
    CASE WHEN (ALS.SID = 6 OR ALS.SID = 7) AND ASIP.SiteID = @iSID 
        THEN ISNULL(ALS.Add / NULLIF(count,0),0.0)
                           ELSE CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (4, 6) AND @forecast = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE IAOD.pack END - 
                                CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) AND @forecast = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE IAOD.packP END + 
                                CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) AND @forecast = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE IAOD.packR END + 
         ISNULL(CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) THEN CAST(NULL AS FLOAT) 
                     ELSE IAOD.packS
                END,
                CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) THEN 0.0 
                     ELSE IAOD.PPStock 
                END) + 
                                CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (4, 6) AND @forecast = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE IAOD.unitsO END -
                                CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) AND @forecast = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE IAOD.unitsP END + 
                                CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) AND @forecast = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE IAOD.unitsR END + 
         ISNULL(CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) 
                     THEN CAST(NULL AS FLOAT) 
                     ELSE IAOD.unitsS 
                END,
                CASE WHEN ALS.SID IN (2, 6) 
                     THEN 0.0 
                     ELSE IAOD.unitsH 
                END) 
    END
)) AS X (MyCalculation)
```